# How to showcase react native expo frontend projects without deploying to stores

Tags: react-native, expo

I already know how to create react native expo applications and deploy them to app stores.
But right now I would like to work on some frontend projects, simply to showcase my skills.
These projects will be displayed on my portfolio.

I would like to know the best way to present them to potential employers.
I know I can build the projects to an APK file that can be downloaded, but I doubt employers would want to download them, as it could be time-consuming. It also restricts me to only employers with Android devices.

What are the best ways to go about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can include a short GIF (or something similar) as a demonstration of your project along with the link to the app build / git repo, so the employer can quickly view what you've built and still have the option to see it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much native stuff you are doing you can also build them as web projects within expo and display them directly in a browser. You could even mock any native functionality you have for demo purposes.